# Can I easily compile u-boot with more commands for arm versatile bp

Tags: arm, freebsd, qemu, u-boot

I have compiled u-boot from u-boot-2013.01.y branch for versatilebp board (arm), and I need fatload command that is not present in this configuation. 
I'm running u-boot under qemu

```
DRAM:  128 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
Using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   SMC91111-0
Warning: SMC91111-0 using MAC address from net device

VersatilePB # fat
Unknown command 'fat' - try 'help'
VersatilePB # help
?       - alias for 'help'
base    - print or set address offset
bdinfo  - print Board Info structure
bootm   - boot application image from memory
bootp   - boot image via network using BOOTP/TFTP protocol
cmp     - memory compare
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
dhcp    - boot image via network using DHCP/TFTP protocol
env     - environment handling commands
erase   - erase FLASH memory
flinfo  - print FLASH memory information
go      - start application at address 'addr'
help    - print command description/usage
iminfo  - print header information for application image
loop    - infinite loop on address range
md      - memory display
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing address)
mtest   - simple RAM read/write test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
protect - enable or disable FLASH write protection
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
setenv  - set environment variables
tftpboot- boot image via network using TFTP protocol
version - print monitor, compiler and linker version
VersatilePB #
```

I need fatload to load file containing image of fat filesystem containing kernel of freebsd. Can I somehow change compile config for that board to compile u-boot with fatload command? Or it's just not possible/not supported for that board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done more or less exactly this for a Versatile AB, it's most certainly possible. The simplest way is to find where that board's command set is defined, and hack in the commands you want by [defining the relevant `CONFIG_CMD_*` symbols](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=README;h=53fc28e7606524702717a99e21cad0c28b76e013;hb=33711bdd4a4dce942fb5ae85a68899a8357bdd94#l1047). In this case, that place is [include/configs/versatile.h](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=include/configs/versatile.h;h=de23375cd5eacaaae7e0a14916ca8215c11a0b13;hb=33711bdd4a4dce942fb5ae85a68899a8357bdd94#l81).

Looking at my checkout of 2015.07, I seem to have added, among others (I think I was trying to convince the MMC to work at the time), these lines:

```
#define CONFIG_CMD_FAT
#define CONFIG_DOS_PARTITION           1
```

Comment: have you succeded in bringing MMC to work? I was told in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035025/what-is-a-structure-of-u-boot-flash-file-arm-versatile-pb that for example versatile pb does not support MMC.

Comment: That was on a real board - I've no idea about QEMU, but I wouldn't be too surprised if it wasn't emulated there. And yeah, either way it's not supported in U-boot's Versatile config - I was hacking the PL180 driver in from some other board (I think I got stuck on the card detect GPIO and went back to doing real work).